# Set expiry date and save value in table magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, date, datetime

I want to set expiry date for let say store credit, I have created custom column by installschema in table as:

```
{
        $table = $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('magento_customerbalance_history'),
            'created_at',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                'nullable' => 'false',
                'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT,
                'comment' => 'Creation Date'
            ]
        );
}
```

I want to create a column 'expiry date', formula could be:

> $expiry_date = $created_at + $one_month;

How to do this manipulation and save value in Table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code to get next month.

```
$nextmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, date("d"),   date("Y"));

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime */
$dateTime = $obj->create(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime::class);

echo $dateTime->gmtDate(); // 2019-07-18 09:35:19
echo "<br>";
echo $dateTime->gmtDate(null, $nextmonth); // 2019-08-18 00:00:00
```